# Memcache-based rate-limiting algorithm? (Token bucket?)

Tags: google-app-engine, rate-limiting

I'm looking for an efficient approach to rate-limiting request from Google App Engine to a third party service.  The third party service rate limits requests on a per-account basis, and on the Google App Engine side, most of the work is carried out inside tasks.  Token buckets are a great general algorithm here.

Q: what approach can be used to efficiently rate-limit requests on a per-account rather than per-service basis?

This should not involve setting up rates on GAE task queues as the number of requests per account and the number of accounts serviced will vary greatly.  For performance reason I'm most interested in memcache-based (incr/decr?) ideas!

I think this boils down to memcache-based token bucket?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I kept this project as a bookmark a while ago : http://code.google.com/p/gaedjango-ratelimitcache/

Not really an answer to your specific question but maybe it could help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it's a top search result and I thought others might find an alternative I made useful. It's a bit more granular (down to the second), simple (only a single function), and performant (only one memcache lookup) than the solution above:

```
import webapp2
from functools import wraps
from google.appengine.api import memcache


def rate_limit(seconds_per_request=1):
  def rate_limiter(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
      added = memcache.add('%s:%s' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.request.remote_addr or ''), 1,
                           time=seconds_per_request, namespace='rate_limiting')
      if not added:
        self.response.write('Rate limit exceeded.')
        self.response.set_status(429)
        return
      return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
  return rate_limiter


class ExampleHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @rate_limit(seconds_per_request=2)
  def get(self):
    self.response.write('Hello, webapp2!')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your response doesn't implement token-bucket rate limiting as per the OPs request. See https://github.com/bradbeattie/django-cache-throttle/blob/master/cache_throttle/utils.py for my Python implementation of such an algorithm and see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket for more information about token buckets.

Comment: Eh, I took the token bucket thing as more of a suggestion than a requirement. Also this was mostly for others who may not require token bucketing, since this page is still a top SERP for "App Engine rate limit".

Out of curiosity though, what advantages does token bucketing provide over my approach? It would seem to handle "burstiness" a bit better, but are there other advantages I'm not thinking of? It would take only minor modification to allow custom rate-limiting keys.

Comment: Yeah, you're right on the money in that it's largely about handling burstiness. Suppose you want to allow a user 24 actions in a day. You could limit them to one per hour, but that throttles them tighter if they want to consume the 24 right now. A token bucket solution better matches the intended behaviour, I'd argue.

Comment: A rate limiting algorithm must work reliably under arbitrarily heavy loads. The solution by @0x24a537r9 should work well in a heavily concurrent environment (assuming that memcache.add() throws errors correctly on collisions even under extreme load). Brad's algorithm doesn't actually do the difficult part (managing memcache under load).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I implemented token bucket with memcache on GAE:

Edit: taking (another) stab at this.

This is borrowed in part from https://github.com/simonw/ratelimitcache/blob/master/ratelimitcache.py

```
def throttle(key, rate_count, rate_seconds, tries=3):
    '''
    returns True if throttled (not enough tokens available) else False
    implements token bucket algorithm
    '''
    client = memcache.Client(CLIENT_ARGS)
    for _ in range(tries):
        now = int(time.time())
        keys = ['%s-%s' % (key, str(now-i)) for i in range(rate_seconds)]
        client.add(keys[0], 0, time=rate_seconds+1)
        tokens = client.get_multi(keys[1:])
        tokens[keys[0]] = client.gets(keys[0])
        if sum(tokens.values()) >= rate_count:
            return True
        if client.cas(keys[0], tokens[keys[0]] + 1, time=rate_seconds+1) != 0:
            return False
    logging.error('cache contention error')
    return True
```

Here are usage examples:

```
def test_that_it_throttles_too_many_requests(self):
    burst = 1
    interval = 1
    assert shared.rate_limit.throttle('test', burst, interval) is False
    assert shared.rate_limit.throttle('test', burst, interval) is True


def test_that_it_doesnt_throttle_burst_of_requests(self):
    burst = 16
    interval = 1
    for i in range(burst):
        assert shared.rate_limit.throttle('test', burst, interval) is False
    time.sleep(interval + 1) # memcache has 1 second granularity
    for i in range(burst):
        assert shared.rate_limit.throttle('test', burst, interval) is False
```